# Convert an image into green scale

Tags: android

### Convertimage in green scale

I m trying to convert image in green scale .. but my code given below not working properly .. plz tell me whats wrong with this code??? How can i convert image in green scale .. Suggestions and solutions required please..

```
     package com.example.tayyabamaryam.greenscale;

             import android.graphics.Bitmap;
             import android.graphics.Color;
             import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
             import android.os.Bundle;
             import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
             import android.view.View;
             import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    ImageView im;

    private Bitmap bmp;
    private Bitmap operation;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.green) ;
        im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img) ;

        BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable();
        bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
    }
    public void green(View view){
                operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight(), 
                bmp.getConfig());

        for(int i=0; i<bmp.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<bmp.getHeight(); j++){
                int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
                int r = Color.red(p);
                int g = Color.green(p);
                int b = Color.blue(p);
                int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

                r =  0;
                g =  g+150;
                b =  0;
                alpha = 0;
                operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(Color.alpha(p), r, g, b));
            }
        }
        im.setImageBitmap(operation);
    }
}
```

Comment: `but my code given below not working properly`. Well tell what goes wrong before you ask whats wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable();
                Bitmap bmp = abmp.getBitmap();

                return applyGscale(bmp);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                im.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }.execute();

    // method 
    public static Bitmap applyGscale(Bitmap src) {
                            // constant factors
                            final double GS_RED = 0.299;
                            final double GS_GREEN = 0.587;
                            final double GS_BLUE = 0.114;

                            // create output bitmap
                            Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());
                            // pixel information
                            int A, R, G, B;
                            int pixel;

                            // get image size
                            int width = src.getWidth();
                            int height = src.getHeight();

                            // scan through every single pixel
                            for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                                for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                                    // get one pixel color
                                    pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                                    // retrieve color of all channels
                                    A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                                    R = Color.red(pixel);
                                    G = Color.green(pixel);
                                    B = Color.blue(pixel);
                                    // take conversion up to one single value
                                    R = G = B = (int)(GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);
                                    // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                                    bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
                                }
                            }

                            // return final image
                            return bmOut;
                        }
```

Comment: R u set image in imageview?

Answer (score 0):

User Color Filter

for example :

```
 icon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```